# Why is Popup not shown?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7.1

First:

```
public MainPage()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    this.Loaded += new RoutedEventHandler(MainPage_Loaded);
}

void MainPage_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Verdienen v = new Verdienen(4, 3);
}
```

and then:
    public Verdienen(int attesaInSecondiIniziale = 20, int attesaInSecondiFinale = 8)
        {
            this.AttesaInSecondiIniziale = attesaInSecondiIniziale;
            this.AttesaInSecondiIniziale = attesaInSecondiFinale;
            MostraPerQuestaSezione = false;

```
        popup = new Popup();
        Border border = new Border();
        border.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.LightGray);
        border.Margin = new Thickness(3);
        StackPanel panelVerticale = new StackPanel();
        panelVerticale.Orientation = Orientation.Vertical;
        AdControl control = new AdControl();
        panelVerticale.Children.Add(control);
        StackPanel panelOrizzontale = new StackPanel();
        panelOrizzontale.Orientation = Orientation.Horizontal;
        Button bAltreApp = new Button();
        bAltreApp.Content = "";
        bAltreApp.Tap += new EventHandler<GestureEventArgs>(bAltreApp_Tap);
        Button bVota = new Button();
        bVota.Tap += new EventHandler<GestureEventArgs>(bVota_Tap);
        bVota.Content = "";
        panelOrizzontale.Children.Add(bAltreApp);
        panelOrizzontale.Children.Add(bVota);
        panelVerticale.Children.Add(panelOrizzontale);
        border.Child = panelVerticale;
        popup.Child = border;

        this.ShowPopup();
    }

    private async **System.Threading.Tasks.TaskEx** ShowPopup()
    {
        do
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("thread iniziato. pausa cominciata");
            await System.Threading.Tasks.TaskEx.Delay(1000 *    this.AttesaInSecondiIniziale);
            Debug.WriteLine("thread: fine pausa");
            popup.IsOpen = true;
            await System.Threading.Tasks.TaskEx.Delay(1000 * this.AttesaInSecondiFinale);
            popup.IsOpen = false;
        } while (MostraPerQuestaSezione);
    }
```

Can you please say to me why this code does not show the popup? Note: some not necessary code is not present!
EDIT: Note that *System.Threading.Tasks.TaskEx* is marked as error ("The return state of an async method must be void, Task or Task").

Comment: Where the code of ShowPopup?

Comment: I have upgraded the code. Please, see it another time!

Answer (score 0):

When you use `Thread.Sleep`, you block the UI message pump. This prevents the system from being able to display your popup, since it won't display until it can process messages correctly.

A better approach would be to move this into an async method, and call it after the construction:

```
public async Task ShowPopup(int attesaInSecondiIniziale = 20, int attesaInSecondiFinale = 8)
{
   // Your code...

   do
   {
      await Task.Delay(1000 * this.AttesaInSecondiIniziale);
      this.ShowPopup();
      await Task.Delay(1000 * this.AttesaInSecondiIniziale);
      this.HidePopup();       
   }
   while (MostraPerQuestaSezione);
}
```

By using `Task.Delay` with `await` in an async method, you won't block the UI.  However, this would require targeting WP7.5 with the [async targeting pack](https://nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Bcl.Async).

Comment: ok...But how do you add System.Threading.Tasks?? I can add only System.Threading...
I used "PM> Install-Package System.Threading.Tasks -Pre" in my project but it is not added...

Comment: Excuse me, but it seems await Task.Delay(int) will start only with WP8

Comment: @Spode If you're targeting 7.5, it'll be `await TaskEx.Delay(int)`

Comment: Yes, but I got an error, described in the first post. Please, see it another time.

Comment: System.Threading.Tasks.TaskEx is marked as error ("The return state of an async method must be void, Task or Task").

Comment: @Spode are you targetting WP 7.5?

Answer (score 0):

```
this.ShowPopup(); ...
this.HidePopup();
```

should be

```
popup.ShowPopup(); ...
popup.HidePopup();
```

You are calling `this` and in this context, `this` is a `Verienen` object and you have no

`ShowPopup()` or `HidePopup()` methods

Comment: No...I do not believe it can be the solution because I declared Popup popup as global variable. Thanks! =)

Comment: what is `this` then?   if it's not referencing the object of `Verdienen()` then my understanding of C# and OOP are way off. elaborate!

Comment: Yes, this refers to Verdienen's instance. But it is in this class that I declared Popup popup as global object ;)